# My query join from more than 2 TABLES return double values using same key reference

Tags: sql, join

I'm trying to join more than 2 tables using 1 same key reference,
it works fine when I join two 2 tables using left join like this :

`SELECT userProfile.UserProfileID, userProfile.name, jobPosition.levelname
FROM  master.eliUserProfile userProfile 
LEFT JOIN master.eliJobPosition jobPosition ON userProfile.UserProfileId = jobPosition.UserProfileID 
where userProfile.UserProfileId = '5001'`

Result :

```
userProfileid    | name    |  levelName   |
-----------------+---------+--------------+
5001             | dirdple | Direktur PLE | 
5001             | dirdple | Direktur PLE |
```

But when I want to join another table into it, it return double values, I am using the master table reference (which is UserProfile) :

```
SELECT userProfile.UserProfileID, userProfile.name, jobPosition.levelname, userAcmMapping.UserAcmMappingId, userAcmMapping.RefID
FROM  master.eliUserProfile userProfile 
LEFT JOIN master.eliJobPosition jobPosition 
ON userProfile.UserProfileId = jobPosition.UserProfileID 
LEFT JOIN transactions.eliUserAcmMapping userAcmMapping 
ON userProfile.UserProfileId = userAcmMapping.UserProfileID 
where userProfile.UserProfileId = '5001'
```

and it turned out to resulted like this :

```
userProfileId    | name    | levelName    | UserAcmMappingId | refId |
-----------------+---------+--------------+------------------+-------+
5001             | dirdple | Direktur PLE |        1         |   21  |
5001             | dirdple | Direktur PLE |        7         |   22  |
5001             | dirdple | Direktur PLE |       158        |   23  |
5001             | dirdple | Direktur PLE |        1         |   21  | 
5001             | dirdple | Direktur PLE |        7         |   22  |
5001             | dirdple | Direktur PLE |       158        |   23  |
```

Is it because Iam using the same key(userProfile.UserProfileId)? Fyi, the 3rd table (userAcmMapping) have 3 values with UserProfileId=5001 and 2nd table (jobPosition) have 2 values with UserProfileId=5001.
And the table I want to be referenced is the second table with **2 values** (userProfileId=5001)..

Thank you for any help..

Comment: But you get double values already in the result of the first query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are joining two different tables to one table with the same key. You are joining `jobPositions`  and `userAcmMapping` to `userProfile`. I mean there are two joins on one table with the same field, so the result is doubled.

You should instead join `jobPositions` to `userProfile` and join `userAcmMapping` to `jobPositions`, like this:

```
SELECT userProfile.UserProfileID, userProfile.name, jobPosition.levelname, userAcmMapping.UserAcmMappingId, userAcmMapping.RefID
FROM  master.eliUserProfile userProfile 
LEFT JOIN master.eliJobPosition jobPosition 
ON userProfile.UserProfileId = jobPosition.UserProfileID 
LEFT JOIN transactions.eliUserAcmMapping userAcmMapping 
ON jobPosition.UserProfileID = userAcmMapping.UserProfileID 
where userProfile.UserProfileId = '5001'
```

Here it is one join per table.

**Note:** I didn't test the code, since I don't have actual tables, but it should work.